# Rust - Is semicolon necessary here?

Tags: rust

The purpose of this code is to loop from 1 to 4 and stop.
My question is why if I add or leave the semicolon in the else statement (;) it doesn't matter... the code compile just fine. What's the best approach? Add the semicolon or leave it?

```
fn main() {
    let mut var = 1;
    loop{
        println!("It is now {}", var);
        if var >= 4 {
            println!("Finished the loop");
            break;
            
        } else {
            var = var + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small detail: `var += 1;` is more typical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the trailing semicolon determines the return value of the block. If you leave the semicolon out, the return value is the value of the last expression in the block. With the semicolon included, the return value is always Rust's unit value, the empty tuple `()` (except when the block contains an expression that does not return, in which case the return type is the "never" type `!`, which does not have any values).

In this particular case, there is no semantic difference. Assignment expressions return the unit value as well, i.e. `(var = var + 1) == ()`. However, this is more or less a coincidence. You don't actually want to return any value in that statement, so including the semicolon makes your intention much clearer.

Comment: Well I was almost posting the same answer right before this one, let me support this with the [reference link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#assignment-expressions), which points: _"An assignment expression always produces the unit value."_

Comment: IIRC in this case it matters even less because `break` is a bottom (`!`), so the first branch essentially has no type, and the second branch can thus have any type.

Comment: @Masklinn This isn't true for two reasons. First, the `break` expression is terminated by a semicolon, so the type of the first branch is `()`, and thus the type of the second branch must be the same. And second, a `loop` can't return a value, so the last statement in the loop must always be of type `()` – the code doesn't compile if it has any other type.

Comment: @SvenMarnach [the type of the first branch is not `()`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f13dfda94662e416b4d97502a558866). I don't know if that's a special case of the compiler (as it doesn't just ignore everything following the `break` statement e.g. `break; ""` will trigger a type error), but `break;` and `break` yield the exact same result.

Comment: @Masklinn Interesting! Apparently any expression of type `!` followed by a semicolon is still of type `!`. I didn't know that, but just tried with `panic!()` and `loop {}` as well.

Comment: The exact behaviour is complicated. Apparently any expression of type `!` inside a block changes the meaning of the trailing semicolon from type `()` to `!`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach that certainly makes sense for convenience (`return;` being `()` would really suck), but it *is* rather odd.

Answer (score 3):

The generated binary will be exactly be the same here but don't just think about the compiler, think about the humans reading the code too.

The absence of a semicolon at the end of the last statement of a block has an implied meaning: the value is returned from the block, the value matters.

If the value isn't used, don't return it. Put that semicolon to help humans read the code.

If you don't put that semicolon and configure Clippy to be very annoying, you'll get a warning too due to the [semicolon_if_nothing_returned](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#semicolon_if_nothing_returned) rule.